# Model "A car has to be owned by either a person or a company" in UML

Tags: uml

We will have at least three UML boxes: Company, Car, Person.

The Person can belong to a Company, and a Car has to be owned by either a Person or a Company, but never by none of them.

Is this possible in UML? The question is in multiplicity.

[image]

What should appear in the "?" spots, or should it be modeled somehow differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can model it as a xor constraint.

To show xor you link two associations with a dashed line on which there is a `{xor}`. Note, it has to be in curly brackets since it denotes a constraint. As an alternative (if your modelling tool doesn't support this notation), you may create a note linked to both associations with a single `{xor}` statement in it.

In both cases both associations on the side of Company/Person need `0..1` multiplicity.

Of course if you may have multiple owners and owners may be both Persons or Companies or both, you will use the `{or}` operator instead and multiplicities `0..n`.

You can read more about it in specification, section 7.6.5, figure 7.16 page 37 or [here](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/constraint.html?context=class-diagrams) (you may also find other references).